# handling command output in python

Tags: python

I want to work with the output of a wifi scan command. The output is several lines and I am interested in 2 information out of it. The goal is to have the ESSID and the address in a two dimmension array (hope thats right?) Here is what I got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import re
from time import sleep

# set wifi interface
wif = "wlan0"
```

So I get the command stdout and I find out that to work with this output in a loop I have to use iter

```
# check for WiFis nearby
wifi_out = subprocess.Popen(["iwlist", wif ,"scan"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
wifi_data = iter(wifi_out.stdout.readline,'')
```

Then I used enumerate to have the index and therefore I search for the line with the address and the next line (index + 1) would contain the ESSID

```
for index, line in enumerate(wifi_data):
    searchObj = re.search( r'.* Cell [0-9][0-9] - Address: .*', line, re.M|re.I)
    if searchObj:
        print index, line
        word = line.split()
        wifi = [word[4],wifi_data[index + 1]]
```

Now I have two problems 
1) wifi_data is the wrong Type 
    `TypeError: 'callable-iterator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` 
2) I guess with 
    `wifi = [word[4],wifi_data[index + 1]]` 
I set the the variable every time new instead of have something that appends. But I want a variable that in the and has all ESSIDs together with all corresponding addresses. 
I am new with python, so currently I imaging something like

```
WIFI[0][0] returns ESSID
WIFI[0][1] returns address to ESSID in WIFI[0][0]
WIFI[1][0] returns next ESSID
WIFI[1][1] returns address to ESSID in WIFI[1][0]
```

and so on. Or would be something else in python better to work with such kind of information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
next(wifi_data)
```

since you cannot index into an iterator ... this will give you the next item ... but it may screw up your loop ...

although really you could just do

```
wifi_out = subprocess.Popen(["iwlist", wif ,"scan"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
wifi_data = wifi_out.communicate()[0].splitlines()
```

or even easier perhaps

```
wifi_data = subprocess.check_output(["iwlist",wif,"scan"]).splitlines()
```

and then you will have a list ... which will work more like you expect with regards to accessing the data via index (theres not really a good reason to use an iter for this that I can tell)

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot! I could change my loop, so now I get the two information, as I wanted them to :) Do you also have an idea what the best way would be to save them and work in a loop later with them?